# Suggestion to revert to older revision got rejected as "too much change"

Tags: feature-request, support, review, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I wish to call the suggested edits review process to question.

Specifically I want the reviewers to be alerted when a suggested edit is **reverting to an older version** of the post, ideally with an option to **compare** the suggested edit **to the older version**.

I reverted this question to an older version because the OP had replaced the original question with his/her own sandbox testing *(presumably the user is new to the site and does not know this is not allowed)*. I also made very minor grammar changes but otherwise did not change anything else.

> [“Main method not found” error when starting program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21470607)

On my [first attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3942005) to make the revert, I wrote the following as the edit comment:

> reverting to original question.. was replaced by OP with sandbox attempts..., fixed grammar

However It got rejected **very quickly** by three reviewers, getting an accept vote from only one reviewer.

I [attempted again](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3942024), but this time I wrote the comment as follows:

> Reviewers PLEASE READ: I am reverting this post to the original question which the OP replaced with his own code format testing. Please CHECK before rejecting the suggested edit...

This time, it got accepted after some time *(presumably the accepting reviewers took time to verify my edit after reading my attention-seeking comment)*, but I still got two reject votes *fairly quickly*.

It seems the rejecting reviewers were easily **misled** into thinking I am introducing new content and what I'm doing *"changes too much in the original post; the original meaning or intent of the post would be lost"*.

I suggest that when a suggested edit is made by choosing a revision older than the most recent one, this should be alerted to the reviewers in a highlighted, easily-noticeable message similar to the following:

> **This suggested edit reverts to an older revision of the post. Please compare with the older revision before voting.**

Comment: *"Congratulations, this edit should have been rejected and you passed"* That is a terrible incentive!

Comment: On a related side-note, it would also have been helpful if votes could be contested with the reviewers with an ability to send them messages to clarify with them and ask them to change their reject vote to accept vote. It will also avoid having to re-submit the same edit and bite my teeth hoping better reviewers will see it.

Comment: Definitely important to have a descriptive attention grabbing revision note for an edit like that (like you did), and it was approved that way. Having a rollback indicator isn't a bad idea but then in the 600 reviews I've completed (+ probably another 1000 I've skipped) I don't think I've ever seen a suggested rollback, so not really a big issue.